# Determine if the function $1/\lfloor 1/x\rfloor$ is integrable on $[0,2]$

Tags: calculus, integration, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Is this function integrable on $[0,2]$?
$$\cfrac{1}{\left\lfloor\cfrac{1}{x}\right\rfloor}$$

I have suspicion that it is, but I'm unsure of how I could determine if that's true.

Comment: I don't have the tools provided by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus; just a note.

Comment: So, are you to argue using partitions? The function is bounded. The discontinuities can be enumerated. Does this connect with any results you have about integrals?

Comment: I thnk it is not integrable.

Comment: The boundedness, yes; the discontinuities, no.

Comment: I think it is integrable, I'm just unsure of how to show that it is.

Comment: So it's bounded, but would that mean I have to show that $U(f,P) - L(f,P) < \epsilon$?

Comment: Wait a moment. When $x\in (1,2]$, the denominator is $0$. So.. does not look very good for integrability. Unless there's a typo in the statement.

Comment: Hint: Divide $[0,2]$ in smaller intervals on which the function is constant.

Comment: @Fundamental So it can't be integrated from $(1,2]?$ What about $(0, 1]?$

Comment: Try this: http://www.math.utah.edu/~yael/3210_public/exams/Integral.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\displaystyle\int_0^2\frac1{\bigg\lfloor\dfrac1x\bigg\rfloor}~dx~=~\int_\tfrac12^\infty\frac1{\lfloor u\rfloor}~\dfrac{du}{u^2}~,~$ which clearly diverges, since $\lfloor u\rfloor=0$ for $u\in(0,1)$.

Comment: The variable change was $x\mapsto\dfrac1x$. If, on the other hand, the upper limit would have been $1$ instead of $2$, then it would have converged to $\zeta(2)-1=\dfrac{\pi^2}6-1$.

Comment: This involves the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: No, just a simple variable change.

Answer (score 2):

Note that for $x>1$ we have $\newcommand{\dcc}[1]{\left\lfloor#1\right\rfloor}\newcommand{\dd}{\,\mathrm{d}}\dcc{\frac1x}=0$, so this function is undefined for $x>1$. If we work with the interval $[0,1]$ instead we get

$$\int_0^1 \frac1{\dcc{\frac1x}} \dd x =
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{\frac1{n+1}}^{\frac1n} \frac1{\dcc{\frac1x}} \dd x \overset{(*)}=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n \left(\frac1n -\frac1{n+1}\right)=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n \cdot \frac 1{n(n+1)} =
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2(n+1)} < +\infty.$$

$(*)$: We used that for $\frac1{n+1}<x\le\frac1n$ we have $n\le\frac1x<n+1$ and thus $\dcc{\frac1x}=n$

So the integral from $0$ to $1$ is finite.

Drawing graph of the function might help with better understanding of the problem, so I'll add some plots from WolframAlpha. (But you should be able to draw something like this also by hand, without using any software.)

Graph of $\dcc{\frac1x}$: [plot 1/floor(1/x) from 0 to 2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+floor%281%2Fx%29+from+0+to+2)

[image: Graph of floor(1/x)]

Graph of $\frac1{\dcc{\frac1x}}$: [plot 1/floor(1/x) from 0 to 2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+1%2Ffloor%281%2Fx%29+from+0+to+2)

[image: Graph of 1/floor(1/x)]

Area under the graph of $\frac1{\dcc{\frac1x}}$: [integrate 1/floor(1/x) from 0 to 2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+floor%281%2Fx%29+from+0+to+2)

[image: Area under 1/floor(1/x)]

Comment: The sum we got is calculated, for example, in these posts: [Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$=$1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2(n+1)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1685733) or [Sum of series with addition: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2(n+1)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3372040)