# Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$=$1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2(n+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I'm really at loss with this problem. I should prove that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2(n+1)}$$

Only thing I managed to do by working the left side was

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = 1+\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=1+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$$

How am I supposed to get to the right form?

Comment: Try a little partial fraction decomposition on $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**

Note the following:

$$\frac{1}{n^2(n+1)}=\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$ $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})=1$$

Can you continue from here?

Answer (score 1):

So if I got it right it goes something like this
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2(n+1)}$$
$$=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{n^2} - \frac{1}{n(n+1)})$$
$$=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{n(n+1)})$$
$$=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})$$
and because of telescoping property
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}) = 1 $$
so
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} - 1 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}.$$