# Sum of series with addition: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2(n+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am looking at some homework where I have:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2(n+1)}$

How can I sum this?

I know that

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$

and also that

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+1)}=1$

But I just can't see or find the connection

Comment: See also: [Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$=$1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2(n+1)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1685733)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$=$1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2(n+1)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1685733/prove-that-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n2-1-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n2n)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint:

$$\dfrac1{n^2(n+1)}=\dfrac{n+1-n}{n^2(n+1)}=\dfrac1{n^2}-\dfrac1{n(n+1)}$$

$$\dfrac1{n(n+1)}=\dfrac{n+1-n}{n(n+1)}=?$$

See [Telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)

Answer (score 7):

**HINT**

$$\frac{1}{n^2(n+1)}=\frac1{n^2}+\frac1{n+1}-\frac1{n}$$

Answer (score 5):

Very simple 
$\dfrac{1}{n^2(n+1)} =\dfrac{(n+1)-n}{n^2(n+1)} =\dfrac{1}{n^2} -\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)} $

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks, but can it really be true that this sums up to some strange real number? I would think homework would be some friendly number

Comment: I dont whether it is special or not but the answer to question is $0.644934067$

Comment: Ok thanks, seems to be $\pi^2/6-1$

Comment: Yeah sure its that only